# WPF CodedUI: ArgumentException when getting ColumnHeaders on a WpfTable if a column is collapsed

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, visual-studio-2013, coded-ui-tests

When I try to get the column headers on a DataGrid using the WpfTable.ColumnHeaders property, I get an argument exception, if and only if one of the columns in the grid has its visibility set to Collapsed.

Typically:

```
var columnHeaders = myUiMap.Grid.ColumnHeaders;
```

will throw this exception:

```
System.ArgumentException: The native object System.Windows.Automation.AutomationElement is not supported by technology manager UIA.
```

That looks like a bug in the automation framework, but I am not quite sure. Would you know why this happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using Visibility.Hidden instead of Visibility.Collapsed